# Understanding and Configuring Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got a MVC Application with only the default route specified as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
            "Default", _
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
            New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
            )
```

First of all, I'd like to understand the meaning of the word "Default" in the first parameter of this route, in order to build a route that can work as I intend it to.

With the following, I wanted to be able to invoke the index of the ApplicationModule controller without having to specifically mention the index method in the Url, much like I do for the other controllers:

```
href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>ApplicationModule/Index/<%= Html.Encode(app.id) %>"
```

If I remove the /Index from this Url, the application tells me that the said resource was not found.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default is just the name of the route.

You can set up a route that will do this, but it will likely break the rest of your site.

The problem is that you want it to automatically treat the 2nd parameter in the URL as the ID, but how does it know that it is an ID rather than an action method name?

Comment: E.g.: the following Url calls the index method of the Article Controller without specifying it - href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>Article". Is the problem due to the id?

Comment: Yes, it is treating the id as the action name.

Comment: So in the end I must stick with the Index strictly specified in my Url, am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to specify a parameter to pass to an action, you have to specify the action name. So in this case it must be Index/id

Comment: Thanks, now I understand at least how it works. One last question, and regarding what Bob Vale said: does MVC cycle through the various routes if the previous one failed to fulfill the request based on the Url specified?

Comment: It will match the first route that matches the pattern of the URL. If that route fails, you will get an error.

Comment: Actually, you will not get an error if you keep the default route that is given to you by MVC during project setup. That is considered as your fallback route. If your first route is not a match, the second one will be tried, if that fails it goes for the third one, etc. until the match is found. problem with misconfiguration of routes is that you will not get a nice and fancy name, but rather a lot of query string parameters.

Comment: See my answer for another alternative.  Catch the unknown action and pass it to your index action..

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the routing mechanism takes practice and experience. The idea behind routing mechanism is to take the incoming URL and obtain the handler (IHttpHandler) object that will handle the request. As for your question, the first parameter of MapRoute extension method is the name of a route. When you set up an MVC project you get:

```
routes.MapRoute( _ 
    ' "Default" is your route name. It can be null, "" or some other name that you give it
    "Default", _     

    ' This is your URL with parameters
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _

    ' Parameter defaults
    new { .controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional })
```

The route name paremeter allows your to invoke the controller and action just by using the name. For example, instead of:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { paramId = 1234 });
```

you can use route name like

```
return RedirectToRoute("MyRouteName", new { paramId = 1234 });
```

As for the configuration of the route it should be something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    "YourRouteName", _   
    "ApplicationModule/{id}", _
    New With {.controller = "ApplicationModule", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParemeter.Optional })
```

And place this new route configuration above the default one that MVC gives you when you create a project, otherwise your new route configuration will never be caught and the default one will always attempt to resolve incoming URL's.

And one more suggestion for the end, instead of using:

```
href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>ApplicationModule/Index/<%= Html.Encode(app.id) %>"
```

use Url.Content like this:

```
href="<%= Url.Content("Index", "ApplicationModule", With New { .id = app.id })"
```

This will automatically resolve your virtual path and looks a bit neater.
If you get a chance to get hold of Steven Sanderson's Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework, you will get a much clearer picture about URLs and routing mechanism.

Best regards,

Huske

Comment: Excellent explanation that even a rookie like me can understand. +1 for the tips

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 1: "Default" is just a name for the route for your internal reference, helps you describe what the route is for.

Answer to 2: Add this mapping in BEFORE the default one.

```
routes.MapRoute( _  
  "ApplicationModuleIndex", _
  "ApplicationModule/{id}", _
  New With {.controller = "ApplicationModule", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _  
)
```

This may have the side effect that the url "ApplicationModule/Action" (ie no id) may just call the index action instead and you may need an addition route (before the previous one) of

```
 routes.MapRoute( _  
                "ApplicationModule", _
                "ApplicationModule/{action}", _
                New With {.controller = "ApplicationModule", .action = "Index"} _  
                New With {.action = "Index|Action1|Action2"} _
      )
```

Replace the `"Index|Action1|Action2"` with a `|` seperated list of actions that are valid

Alternatively you could just dump adding these new routes and override the `HandleUnknownAction`

eg.

in your ApplicationModule controller

```
protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName) {
  var result = Index(actionName);
  result.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
}
```

Comment: How will it tell the difference between those two actions if the users is taken to 'ApplicationModule/1234'?

Comment: Have I missunderstood the routing, doesn't it move on when the first fails?

Comment: I think it uses the first route that matches the pattern. There does not appear to be any checking to see if the url is actually valid.

Comment: Using Constraints to seperate